# Создание копии объекта TextView

Tags: java, android

Я создал объект `TextView`, задал ему все необходимые свойства. Теперь мне необходимо сгенерировать множество таких же объектов, но с разными координатами. Можно ли создать копию данного объекта? Знаю только как получить ссылку на объект.

Comment: В ООП создание новых объектов, как правило, происходит не клонированием уже существующих, а созданием нового экземпляра объекта `myObject =new Object()`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вызвать у объекта метод `clone()`. Почитать можно [тут](http://javateaching.blogspot.ru/2011/11/clone.html)

Answer (score 0):

Создайте метод, который будет возвращать объект, в вашем случае `TextView`, с необходимыми вам свойствами, общие для всех создаваемых объектов - в теле метода, изменяющиеся - передавать аргументами метода:

```
private TextView myTextView (int x, int y){

   TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    // установка необходимых свойств объекта
   return textView;
}
```

использование:

```
TextView textView1 = myTextView (15, 20);
TextView textView2 = myTextView (40, 20);
```

PS: Задавать какие то абсолютные координаты для виджетов в андроид-разработке является плохой практикой - так не делается, по причине того, что существует большое количество устройств с разными размерами и разрешениями экранов - на разных устройствах такой подход даст разное расположение виджетов.

Comment: А каким образом в данной ситуацию добавить обработку события? К примеру, чтобы вызывался метод при клики по этому объекту?